# SQLServer2008 - Custom templates not showing in Solution Explorer

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008

Hello.

New templates I create in Template explorer are not showing in the solution explorer

Template explorer > Stored Procedure > New folder - Custom > usp_NewStoredProcedure > Save.

I can then see new SP in template explorer.

However when I try and use the new template in Solution Explorer

Solution Explorer > Project1 > add > new item > Stored Procedure

The custom folder isn't there.

Do I need to update a cache somewhere?

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates are independent entities that you use to quickly access pieces of code. While solution is where files are stored pertaining to your solution, excluding the templates that you create for future quick access.

You would want to create a template for something that frequently occurs in your database project and put it into your template explorer. While in solution folder you store all the files and scripts that have anything to do with this particular project. Say, if I open another project all my templates are going to be available to me because those are **templates**.

Comment: Denis, thats great cheers for clearing that one up for me. I'll stop trying to find a work around and actually get on with some work now. Many thanks again.